# Admob interstitial Ads aren't clickable when called from Webview

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, admob, android-jsinterface

Hey I have a web html5 game and I built an app for it, to monetize it with Admob.
I use JavaScript Interface to handle app event from the JavaScript code.

Most of the things works fine but the ads shown are not clickable.
Part of them are completely unclickable - You cannot click on 'close' button, 'x' icon and 'install' button (to move to the android play and download the app from the ad). In other times only the 'install' button doesn't work, or the timer doesn't count down just writes '30 seconds left'.

Here's manifest file.
my details replaced with "xxx"

```
<manifest
    package="com.example.app"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.xxxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxx"
        />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="xxxxxx xxxxxxxx"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="false"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,HardcodedDebugMode"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:label">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <receiver android:name="com.tenjin.android.TenjinReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission> <!-- Required to get network connectivity (i.e. wifi vs. mobile) -->
</manifest>
```

Here's main activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings ws= myWebView.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    ws.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "MyJSClient");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    myWebView.loadUrl(gameUrl);

    if(allowInterstitialAds){
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        if(isTest){
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(TESTadmobUnitIdInterstitial);
        } else{
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(admobAdUnitIdInterstitial);
        }

        loadInterstitialAd();
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(){
                Log.i(TAG,"ad successfully loaded");
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                makeWebviewVisible();
                myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(window.onload = function(){onAdClosed();})()");
                // Load the next interstitial.
                loadInterstitialAd();
            }
        });
    }
}

public void loadInterstitialAd(){
    Log.i(TAG,"loadInterstitialAd function called");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

public void startInterstitialAdProcess(){
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Ad will run now");
        hideWebView();
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        loadInterstitialAd();
    }
    else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Ad not loaded");
    }
}

public void hideWebView(){

    Log.i(TAG,"hiding webview");
    myWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void makeWebviewVisible(){
    Log.i(TAG,"making webview visible");
    myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(myWebView != null){
        myWebView.onPause();
        myWebView.pauseTimers();
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(window.onload = function(){onPause();})()");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    TenjinSDK instance = TenjinSDK.getInstance(this, TenjinApiKey);
    instance.connect();

    if(myWebView != null){
        myWebView.onResume();
        myWebView.resumeTimers();
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(window.onload = function(){onResume();})()");
    }
}

public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void JSshowInterstitialVideo(){
        Log.i(TAG,"JSshowInterstitialVideo called in the app jsinterface");
        displayLoadedAd();
    }
 }
```

I tried to fix it for days
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but may help someone.

pauseTimers() is culprit here. Remove that to resolve the issue.
Executing it when pausing the activity freezes everything including Advertisement related webviews.

As per documentation. pauseTimers is a Global call.

> Pauses all layout, parsing, and JavaScript timers for all WebViews. This is a global requests, not restricted to just this WebView. This can be useful if the application has been paused.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
 mInterstitialAd.show();
//here call webview
}else{
//here call webview some time not load ad so, it open webview}
```

Use this method to solve your problem.
First to onCreate() in load ad and ad is load than is show and ad is close and open webview. If ad is not load for internet problem so you call directly webview. If you test in real device so you add testDeviceId.